# Best way to extract specific parts from html / json page?

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have the following that is returned from python requests:

```
{"error":{"ErrorMessage":"
<div>
<p>To protect your privacy, this form will not display details such as a clinical or assisted collection. If you believe that the information detailed above is incomplete or incorrect, please tell us here 
    <a href=\\"http:\\/\\/www.southhams.gov.uk\\/wastequestion\\">www.southhams.gov.uk\\/wastequestion<\\/a><\\/p><\\/div>","CodeName":"Success","ErrorStatus":0},"calendar":{"calendar":"
        <div class=\\"wsResponse\\">To protect your privacy, this form will not display details such as a clinical or assisted collection. If you believe that the information detailed above is incomplete or incorrect, please tell us here 
            <a href=\\"http:\\/\\/www.southhams.gov.uk\\/wastequestion\\">www.southhams.gov.uk\\/wastequestion<\\/a><\\/div>"},"binCollections":{"tile":[["
                <div class=\'collectionDiv\'>
                    <div class=\'fullwidth\'>
                        <h3>Organic Collection Service (Brown Organic Bin)<\\/h3><\\/div>
                            <div class=\\"collectionImg\\">
                                <img src=\\"https:\\/\\/southhams.fccenvironment.co.uk\\/library\\/images\\/brown bin.png\\" \\/><\\/div>\\n                    
                                <div class=\'wdshDetWrap\'>Your brown organic bin collection is 
                                    <b>Fortnightly<\\/b> on a 
                                        <b>Thursday<\\/b>.
                                            <br\\/> \\n                    Your next scheduled collection is 
                                            <b>Friday, 29 May 2020<\\/b>. 
                                                <br\\/>
                                                <br\\/>
                                                <a href=\\"https:\\/\\/www.southhams.gov.uk\\/article\\/3427\\">Read more about the Organic Collection Service &gt;<\\/a><\\/div><\\/div>"],["
                                                    <div class=\'collectionDiv\'>
                                                        <div class=\'fullwidth\'>
                                                            <h3>Recycling Collection Service (Recycling Sacks)<\\/h3><\\/div>
                                                                <div class=\\"collectionImg\\">
                                                                    <img src=\\"https:\\/\\/southhams.fccenvironment.co.uk\\/library\\/images\\/SH_two_rec_sacks.png\\" \\/><\\/div>\\n                    
                                                                    <div class=\'wdshDetWrap\'>Your recycling sacks collection is 
                                                                        <b>Fortnightly<\\/b> on a 
                                                                            <b>Thursday<\\/b>.
                                                                                <br\\/> \\n                    Your next scheduled collection is 
                                                                                <b>Friday, 29 May 2020<\\/b>. 
                                                                                    <br\\/>
                                                                                    <br\\/>
                                                                                    <a href=\\"https:\\/\\/www.southhams.gov.uk\\/article\\/3383\\">Read more about the Recycling Collection Service &gt;<\\/a><\\/div><\\/div>"],["
                                                                                        <div class=\'collectionDiv\'>
                                                                                            <div class=\'fullwidth\'>
                                                                                                <h3>Refuse Collection Service (Grey Refuse Bin)<\\/h3><\\/div>
                                                                                                    <div class=\\"collectionImg\\">
                                                                                                        <img src=\\"https:\\/\\/southhams.fccenvironment.co.uk\\/library\\/images\\/grey bin.png\\" \\/><\\/div>\\n                    
                                                                                                        <div class=\'wdshDetWrap\'>Your grey refuse bin collection is 
                                                                                                            <b>Fortnightly<\\/b> on a 
                                                                                                                <b>Thursday<\\/b>.
                                                                                                                    <br\\/> \\n                    Your next scheduled collection is 
                                                                                                                    <b>Thursday, 04 June 2020<\\/b>. 
                                                                                                                        <br\\/>
                                                                                                                        <br\\/>
                                                                                                                        <a href=\\"https:\\/\\/www.southhams.gov.uk\\/article\\/3384\\">Read more about the Refuse Collection Service &gt;<\\/a><\\/div><\\/div>"]]}}
```

I would like to extract the following for each collectiondiv (3)

Organic Collection Service (Brown Organic Bin) 
Friday, 29 May 2020

Recycling Collection Service (Recycling Sacks)
Friday, 29 May 2020

Refuse Collection Service (Grey Refuse Bin)
Thursday, 04 June 2020

currently i have tried loading the response.content into the python json handler but still stuck pulling out the data, so then i tried BeautifulSoup with soup.find_all("div", class_="wdshDetWrap") but still cant pull the exact data out would lxml or the like be a more simplier way?

Thanks for looking

request code:

```
url = "https://southhams.fccenvironment.co.uk/mycollections"

response = requests.request("GET", url)

cookiejar = response.cookies
for cookie in cookiejar:
print(cookie.name,cookie.value)

url = "https://southhams.fccenvironment.co.uk/ajaxprocessor/getcollectiondetails"

payload = 'fcc_session_token={}&uprn=100040282539'.format(cookie.value)
headers = {
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Cookie': 'fcc_session_cookie={}'.format(cookie.value)
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: can you provide the part of the code that returns that? (The actual `requests` part)?

Comment: @chitown88 add to bottom of question, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the json directly then can call on that html value. Once you do that, use beautifulsoup to parse the html and print out the context/text within the tags where it is found:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://southhams.fccenvironment.co.uk/mycollections"

response = requests.get(url)

cookiejar = response.cookies
for cookie in cookiejar:
    print(cookie.name,cookie.value)

url = "https://southhams.fccenvironment.co.uk/ajaxprocessor/getcollectiondetails"

payload = 'fcc_session_token={}&uprn=100040282539'.format(cookie.value)
headers = {
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Cookie': 'fcc_session_cookie={}'.format(cookie.value)
}

jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data = payload).json()


data = jsonData['binCollections']['tile']
for each in data:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(each[0], 'html.parser')
    collection = soup.find('div', {'class':'collectionDiv'}).find('h3').text.strip()
    date = soup.find_all('b')[-1].text.strip()

    print (collection, date)
```

**Output:**

```
Organic Collection Service (Brown Organic Bin) Friday, 29 May 2020
Recycling Collection Service (Recycling Sacks) Friday, 29 May 2020
Refuse Collection Service (Grey Refuse Bin) Thursday, 04 June 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML document from the particular site is not formatted correctly. I still managed a work around (Will be inefficient on a scale of around 1000s of tags).

So it can be improved.

```
headers = soup.find_all('h3')
names = [tag.text[:tag.text.find('<')] for tag in headers]
dates = [tag.find_all('b')[2].text[:tag.find_all('b')[2].text.find('<')] for tag in headers]

print(names)
print(dates)

#Output
['Organic Collection Service (Brown Organic Bin)', 'Recycling Collection Service (Recycling Sacks)', 'Refuse Collection Service (Grey Refuse Bin)']
['Friday, 29 May 2020', 'Friday, 29 May 2020', 'Thursday, 04 June 2020']
```

Comment: Where does the `soup` come from?

Comment: @SaschaM78 it comes from the parsing html using a library called [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Not sure why he didn't include that with the solution

Comment: The OP was already using it. So I just modified his 'request code:' snippet.